# Converting foreign characters in URLs

Tags: url, percent-encoding

Is there a website converting foreign characters into URL format? I need an instant result after submit foreign character into the request.

Examples:

台積電 = %CC%A8%B7e%EB%8A

シャープ = %A5%B7%A5%E3%A9%60%A5%D7

혼 하이 = %26%2354844%3B+%26%2354616%3B%26%2351060%3B

Comment: If you know to use java script, just use `encodeURI` function to get encoded.

Comment: thank you, this should work.